# 'And' Filter visualization

Tags: info-visualisation, filter, analytics

I am designing dashboard, and have a filters panel on the side. 
What is the best way to reflect the user that the filtering is an 'AND' combination and not an 'OR' combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters exist of Filtertype and Attributes. For example: Filter is Size and attributes are 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, etc. Another filter might be color with attributes yellow, blue, red, etc.

If a user selects multiple sizes it will be absolutely clear to the user that this is OR operator without thinking of it this way. But it will be clear, that there will be no item which has two sizes. With color this might be more difficult. Since there might be items with more than one color. But in this case the attributes should be combined like red, red/yellow, yellow, green, etc.

If the user combines filters the expectation will always be that this is an AND operator. If a users chooses attribute 40 in filter size and attribute green in filter color she would not expect to find all items with size 40 in any color and all items in green in any size in the result. The expectation will be that the list shows green items in size 40.

Having said so. By grouping attributes in to filters the behaviour of the filters should be clear. If you have some attributes that should be combined as AND you should us them as filter with only just one attribute. For example 'show items on SALE only'.

Comment: tnx for the response. what do u say about adding a '+' between the attributes, like seen in the image [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/Lx5H7sW.png)

Comment: hmh... I think that the plus sign makes it clear. The drawback is, that this is only the case after selecting the attributes. But I would say, that it would actually be the users expectation considering the content.

Answer (score 0):

**Radio** - for OR

**Checkbox** - for AND

[image]

**EDIT:**

**[image: EDIT:]**

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I am looking for something even more distinct. think for example of an online cloth shop. dress size filter has a checks box because u can look for size 38 and 42. but it does not mean that a single dress has both sizes.

Comment: yes, but when You filtering dresses, you can using checkbox and mark both to display dresses, which products meet these conditions.

You check 38 and 42, and You get every dresses from collection, which size is 38 OR 42.

Comment: In my case, I filter food items. I want it to display for example a chocolate bar that both vegan and gluten-free, not 'or'. I know I will use checkbox, but I was wondering who to reflect the user after the selection that it is only an 'and' combination. Pls see attached image - is it a common practice to add '+' [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/Lx5H7sW.png)

Comment: No, it's not good practise.

Look at picture edit of my answer. you can Add every active filters with possibility to unfilter specific attribute.